# Can the power transfer ranges of wireless charging devices be extended to across a room?

Tags: power, inductance, power-engineering, wireless-charging

Wireless charging devices charge devices by creating a magnetic field that induces an electric field in the device (like transformers), but its strength is inversely proportional to distance squared. Power beaming allows for wider ranges in charging, but produces radiation. Is there a way to increase the wireless power transfer range without radiation exposure to humans or other life?

Comment: Technically: yes, efficiently: no.

Comment: If such a technology existed, you'd know, because somebody would surely try to sell it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Like many sources radiating in 3 dimensions, the 'flux' decreases cubed. e.g. your pickup coil is normally 3mm away, but now it is at the other side of the room 3 meters away. Thus the field strength, and the energy transfer, will be 1000.000.000 smaller.

Let's say at 3mm distance your charger was pumping in 0.5Amps in the primary coil. Now it needs to pump in 500.000.000 amps. Somewhat inefficient...

You could make the coil bigger but then you have to walk around with a phone and 1 meter diameter coil. You might get away with 1000.000 amps at the primary, but it is still very inefficient and difficult to get into your pocket.